# Crossrider Safari button icon tiny

Tags: safari, crossrider

I'm using Crossrider to develop a cross browser extension, it's working fine except that the button icon on Safari is so small you can't really see it. How can I expand it?

I uploaded it as a 128x128 PNG in the settings page.

This is a screen shot from my Retina Macbook Pro, could the issue be related to the retina display?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't checked the image DPI settings in Photoshop. They need to be set to 72 but were in fact 300.

If anyone from Crossrider sees this, it would be great if it were possible to upload a retina sized button icon.

Comment: Currently, the Crossrider framework only supports desktop browsers and images must be 128x128 pixels with resolution 72dpi as noted in the [docs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction). [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]